# What is the best way to leverage Translated picklist values for conditional rendering?

Tags: apex, visualforce, translation-workbench

We are in the process of implementing a set of complex Visualforce pages, with Controller Extensions in a Multi-language environment (that uses the Translation Workbench). One of the items we are trying to address is how to leverage the value of a translated picklist to control conditional rendering.  Is there a "best practice" for this?

For example:

```
public Boolean showAxleTab(){
   boolean b=false;
   if(myrec.complist.contains('Axle')){
      b=true;
   }
   return b;
}
```

The challenge is that the complist picklist might be translated, and the value of Axle may be different.  How have other people handled this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I thought that the value of the picklist is always the same and only title could be translated?

Comment: The picklist values themselves can be translated as well.

Comment: Not sure. With Translation workbench you can only translate picklist value label (title) and not a value itself: `The enumerated field values are fixed and do not change with a user’s language. However, each value may have a specified “label” field that provides the localized label for that value.` ([from here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm#i1435709))

Comment: Interesting, maybe I am overthinking it.  I will do some more testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mast0r was right, the label translates, not the value.